# Nested projects under version control, will this break?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

Before I venture into uncharted territories, I'm wondering if one of you Git gurus can lend some advice.

I've got a solution with three projects under version control at GitHub.

I'm looking to pull down the [lucene.net](/questions/tagged/lucene.net) trunk as a fourth project within my solution so that I can get some of their fixes sooner than when they push those changes to [nuget.org](http://nuget.org).

Will this break my repo by nesting the version-controlled lucene.net project inside my version-controlled solution?

Comment: You should read about git submodules.

Comment: Ah, this is good to know. Maybe you could do a quick writeup as an answer for the next guy? I found a [link](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) you could reference too. I'll accept asap.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following layout:

```
a/
    .git/
    somefile1
    somefile2
    dir1/
        .git/
        file1
        file2
```

If you issue `git add dir1/file1` or `git dd dir1/`, you will just add files like "dir1/file1". But if you do `git add dir1` or `git add .`, git will just add pointer to the last commit in "dir1" subrepository without adding content. It will create submodules (thought for the proper setup you will also need to configure .gitmodules). "git gui" will also see it as candidate for subproject.

You can include files in both independent repositories (like "dir1/file1" in the first, "file1" in the other), and "git checkout" (or other commands) in one repository will be seen like just editing files in the other one.

You should look at the diff (like in "git diff HEAD") before committing to be sure what you are doing. If it is like "Subproject commit b6030fea2687a6133c3a8d97e270485d9b5e552f" then it is just adding a pointer to other repository, if it is regular diff then no subprojects are used and you just adding files from there.